# Oracle Not Equals Operator

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two not equals operator - `!=` and `<>`.

What's the difference between them? I heard that `!=` is more efficient than other for comparing strings. Could anyone give a qualitative comment on this statement.

Comment: If i had to guess, I would say one is equivalence vs equality, like the difference between `!=` and `.equals()` in java. But that's just a guess.

Comment: <code>Connected to:
Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.4.1 - Production
With the Partitioning option
JServer Release 8.1.7.4.1 - Production

SQL> select * from dual where 1!=2;

D
-
X<code>

Comment: sorry, cannot format properly the output. But it was already there before 9i.

Comment: `<>` is more efficient: to type `!=` you have to hold Shift, press `!`, then release Shift, press `=`; to type `<>` you only need to hold Shift, type `<` and `>`, and then release Shift - resulting in faster coding! jk ;)

Comment: `<>` is defined by the SQL standard, `!=` is an extension that most DBMS also understand. If you want to write standard compliant SQL, use `<>`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They are the same (as is the third form, `^=`).

Note, though, that they are still considered different from the point of view of the parser, that is a stored outline defined for a `!=` won't match `<>` or `^=`.

This is unlike `PostgreSQL` where the parser treats `!=` and `<>` yet on parsing stage, so you cannot overload `!=` and `<>` to be different operators.

Comment: they have significant performance difference in oracle 10.2 onwards. please see http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_not_equal_operator.htm

Comment: @shanyangqu - the important part to read from that link is "this note by Scott Canaan *suggests* that in Oracle 10.2, they can produce different execution plans, and hence, different execution speeds" - but in the end, the effect was not proven, and several (valid, IMO) theories that would explain the observed behaviour were presented - none of which suggest that the different syntaxes make any difference at all - e.g. that changing any part of a query may cause a re-parse of the statement, or match a different stored outline.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp those guys bullied me into deleting my own answer, which I believe is correct. sigh......

Comment: @shanyangqu: I don't see your deleted answer (normally I do see deleted answers on questions). Perhaps it was flagged as offensive for other reasons than mere incorrectness?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp different thread. and it wasn't offensive. no need for that Jef http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003127/oracle-operators

Comment: @shanyangqu, thanks, I can see your deleted question and the comments on it. BTW *I* didn't say your post was offensive, I merely suggested it as a possible reason why I couldn't see your post. No need to get huffy.

Comment: @shanyangqu: guys, could you please move this discussion to the chat?

Answer (score 7):

There is no functional or performance difference between the two.  Use whichever syntax appeals to you.

It's just like the use of AS and IS when declaring a function or procedure.  They are completely interchangeable.

Comment: I didn't know you can interchange `IS` and `AS`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

They are the same, but i've heard people say that Developers use `!=` while BA's use `<>`

Comment: That's very funny! *Real programmers use `!=`*

Answer (score 4):

As everybody else has said, there is no difference.  (As a sanity check I did some tests, but it was a waste of time, of course they work the same.)

But there are actually FOUR types of inequality operators: !=, ^=, <>, and ¬=.  See [this page in the Oracle SQL reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions002.htm#i1033286).  On the website the fourth operator shows up as ÿ= but in the PDF it shows as ¬=.  According to the documentation some of them are unavailable on some platforms.  Which really means that ¬= almost never works.

Just out of curiosity, I'd really like to know what environment ¬= works on.

Comment: you can also use the "NOT ( a = b )" syntax

Comment: `Just out of curiosity, I'd really like to know what environment ¬= works on.` - IBM mainframes, where `¬` is the "not" character. From the dark ages, when men were men, women were women, dinosaurs roamed the earth, and computers were water-cooled. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Developers using a mybatis-like framework will prefer != over <>. Reason being the <> will need to be wrapped in CDATA as it could be interpreted as xml syntax. Easier on the eyes too.

Answer (score -2):

The difference is :

"If you use `!=`, it returns sub-second. If you use `<>`, it takes 7 seconds to return. Both return the right answer."

[Oracle not equals (!=) SQL operator](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_not_equal_operator.htm)

Regards