# Mysql clause != , not like or <> which is good to use?

Tags: mysql

Mysql clause != , not like  or <>   which is good to use ? Asking just for knowledge.

```
 SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE NOT columnA = 'x' AND NOT columbB = 'y';
```

or

```
  SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE columnA = 'x' AND columbB != 'y' ;
```

or

```
  SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE columnA = 'x' AND columbB <> 'y'
```

Comment: I prefer `!=` because it's same as in my main programming language. Definately i won't use `NOT`, because it's harder to read

Comment: `<>` and `!=` are identical. `<>` being the "not equals" operator defined by the SQL standard. See here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650851

Comment: Are you looking for `NOT` or `NOT LIKE`? `LIKE` would broaden the scope of values filtered I believe.

Comment: This link may be helpful http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/07/08/sql-difference-between-and-operator-used-for-not-equal-to-operation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever makes you happy. Just kidding. Although `!=` and `<>` are the same. For readability purpose for others who doesnt know how or want to translate `<>` in english, rather than (not equal) `!=` is more safe.