# What is the difference between NOT and != operators in SQL?

Tags: sql

What is the difference between `NOT` and `!=` operators in SQL? I can't understand the difference. I guess they are same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use != or <> for not equal in TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`NOT` *negates* the following condition so it can be used with various operators. `!=` is the [non-standard alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650865/330315) for the `<>` operator which means "not equal".

e.g.

```
NOT (a LIKE 'foo%')
NOT ( (a,b) OVERLAPS (x,y) )
NOT (a BETWEEN x AND y)
NOT (a IS NULL)
```

Except for the `overlaps` operator above could also be written as:

```
a NOT LIKE 'foo%'
a NOT BETWEEN x AND y
a IS NOT NULL
```

In some situations it might be easier to understand to negate a complete expression rather then rewriting it to mean the opposite.

---

`NOT` *can* however be used with `<>` - but that wouldn't make much sense though: `NOT (a <> b)` is the same as `a = b`. Similarly you could use NOT to negate the equality operator `NOT (a = b)` is the same as `a <> b`

Answer (score 8):

This question actually makes a lot more sense than people give it credit for.

Firstly, original SQL not-equal operator was `<>`, and only later on the C-style `!=` was added as far as I know. I personally always use `<>` as `!=` looks strange to me, but I'm old school.

Secondly, of course the original asker didn't mean to compare `NOT` with `!=`, but rather the difference between `NOT a = b` vs. `a != b`. And intuitively there *should* be a difference, but for all I know there *isn't*.

To make this all clear, here is an example session run on PostgreSQL (in Oracle you need more weird stuff such as `SELECT ... FROM DUAL UNION ...`, etc., which I avoid for the sake of brevity):

```
db=#  with tst(a, b) as ( values (1,2), (2,3), (4, null) ) select * from tst;
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 2
 2 | 3
 4 |
(3 rows)

db=#  with tst(a, b) as ( values (1,2), (2,3), (4, null) ) select * from tst where b = 2;
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 2
(1 row)

db=#  with tst(a, b) as ( values (1,2), (2,3), (4, null) ) select * from tst where b != 2;
 a | b
---+---
 2 | 3
(1 row)

db=#  with tst(a, b) as ( values (1,2), (2,3), (4, null) ) select * from tst where not b = 2;
 a | b
---+---
 2 | 3
(1 row)
```

Here we may think that this last query should also have returned the row (4, NULL). But it didn't. In PostgreSQL I can actually inspect this further, as follows:

```
db=#  with tst(a, b) as ( values (1,2), (2,3), (4, null) ) select *, b = 2 as beq2 from tst;
 a | b | beq2
---+---+------
 1 | 2 | t
 2 | 3 | f
 4 |   |
(3 rows)
```

You see that the Boolean expression b = 2 is NULL for the case where `b` is NULL. However, when a Boolean expression is NULL it is treated as *false*, or rather *not true*. And when you negate it with `NOT`, the Boolean value of the expression stays NULL and therefore is still *not true*.

Unfortunately I know of no other way than to handle NULL cases explicitly, so I have to write:

```
db=#  with tst(a, b) as ( values (1,2), (2,3), (4, null) ) select * from tst where b is null or b = 2;
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 2
 4 |
(2 rows)
```

So, instead of writing `NOT <Boolean expression>` you always have to write `a IS NULL OR b IS NULL OR ... OR z IS NULL OR f(a, b, ..., z)` where `a`, `b`, ..., `z` are variables in the given Boolean expression `f(...)`.

It would be so much easier if instead of just `NOT` there were the Boolean operators `MAYBE` and `CANNOT`. So you could write `WHERE MAYBE b = 2` or `WHERE CANNOT b = 2` instead of this complicated OR combination of a bunch of IS NULL tests before your actual condition.

Answer (score 4):

`!=` is a binary operator that returns true if its two arguments are not equal to each other.

`NOT` is a unary operator, which reverses its argument, a Boolean expression.

For example, this expression: `a < 10` is true when `a` is any value less than 10. This condition can be negated: `NOT a < 10`. Negating this condition makes it true in the opposite cases, i.e. when a not less than 10. It's the same as `a >= 10`.

The expression `a != 10` is true when `a` is any value less than 10 or any value greater than 10. This is a completely different case from a condition negated with `NOT`.

Answer (score -2):

Both NOT operator and != almost serve a similar purpose.Both are used in Where clause of an sql query.

NOT operator shows records when a particular condition is not true.
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE NOT Country='Germany'
```

will get you records with all employees with countries other than Germany.

The `!=` operator similarly checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, if values are not equal then condition becomes true.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE Country!='Germany'
```

will get you all rows with country column having country other than Germany.