# Oracle silly 'not in' and 'not equal to' questions

Tags: oracle

It's not really important, but just wondering why the Oracle SQL seems to be quote inconsistent?
I mean why do they have...

```
NOT IN (?,?,?)
```

and

```
!= '?'
```

rather than

```
NOT EQ '?'
```

Just a thought

K

Comment: With `NOT IN (?,?,?)` you compare to a **list of expressions** (or subquery), e.g. numbers. With `!= '?'` you compare with a single **string** literal. Oracle is consistent in this.

Comment: i think you're confusing some things. NOT IN is used to compare with a list of values. The != operator is to compare one value with another. A similar notion to what you wrote as NOT EQ '?'  might be the NOT LIKE '?'

Comment: Actually it's  `<> '?'` in standard SQL

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN ( ?, ? )` is [ISO 9075 SQL standard syntax](http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N2301-2350/32N2311T-text_for_ballot-CD_9075-2.pdf).  I do wonder what symbols could possibly be used to denote "not in".  That seems silly, since "mathematical" symbols such as `!=` are almost self-documenting, and the "set" type symbols needed for "not in" aren't available on most keyboards, nor would they be familiar to most developers.

Note that neither `!=` nor `NOT EQ` are ISO-standard.  The standard "not equals operator" is `<>`, but as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650851/is-there-any-difference-between-and-in-oracle-sql), the `!=` has some advantages.

Answer (score 0):

In the code `NOT IN (?,?,?)` the question marks appear to be positional parameters from a parameterized query, while the code `!= '?'` is a comparison to a string literal.  If you had wanted it parameterized it would have been `!= ?` without the single quotes.